# actionscript 3.0 type coercion error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-maps

I'm trying to move to another frame by clicking a movieclip. I have checked the frame name, etc, but it always gets an error like this whenever I tried to click my MovieClip. The application I made is combining google map with flash. So, when I click the movieclip, it should move to another frame containing google map.

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@2675cf99 to flash.display.MovieClip.
at startMap/movetoMap()
```

This is my code :

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.google.maps.*;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.google.maps.overlays.Marker;
import com.google.maps.services.ClientGeocoder;
import com.google.maps.services.GeocodingEvent;

public class startMap extends MovieClip {

    var gMap : Map = new Map();

    public function startMap() {

        this.x = 700;
        this.y = 150;
        this.scaleX = 0.5;
        this.scaleY = 0.5;
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, movetoMap);
    }

    function movetoMap (e : MouseEvent)
    {
//I think this is where the error took place...
        MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop("mymap"); // move to another frame

                    //the code below is for the next frame
        //trace ("initiating map");
        /*
        gMap.key = "ABQIAAAAkvJLDXCdl31EuFDEitKQ6hTDVs7mYo4hdRoqkWYrrPdtz_Eb9RRJP9mw3bPiboGSX4c0stQsYo4aPQ";
        gMap.sensor = "true";
        gMap.x = 100;
        gMap.y = 50;
        gMap.setSize(new Point(stage.width - 200, stage.height - 100));
        gMap.addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, prepareMap);
        gMap.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, showPoint);
        stage.addChild (gMap);
        */
    }
    /*
    function prepareMap (e : Event)
    {
        doGeoCode ("Jakarta, Indonesia");
    }

    function showPoint (e : MapMouseEvent)
    {
        var revGeoCode : ClientGeocoder = new ClientGeocoder();
        revGeoCode.addEventListener(GeocodingEvent.GEOCODING_SUCCESS,
                function markPlace (e : GeocodingEvent) {
                    var place : Array = e.response.placemarks;
                    var marker : Marker = new Marker (place[0].point);
                    gMap.addOverlay(marker);
                    gMap.setZoom(8, true);
                    gMap.setCenter (marker.getLatLng());
                    marker.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK,
                            function showInfo(e : MapMouseEvent){
                                gMap.openInfoWindow(marker.getLatLng(),
                                    new InfoWindowOptions ({title:"Welcome to", content:place[0].address}));
                            });
                });
        revGeoCode.addEventListener(GeocodingEvent.GEOCODING_FAILURE, 
                function addFailure(e : GeocodingEvent){
                    trace ('fail to geocode');
                });
        revGeoCode.reverseGeocode(e.latLng);
    }

    function doGeoCode (placeName : String)
    {
        var placeInfo : ClientGeocoder = new ClientGeocoder();
        placeInfo.addEventListener(GeocodingEvent.GEOCODING_SUCCESS, 
                function addInfo(e : GeocodingEvent){
                    var place : Array = e.response.placemarks;
                    var mark : Marker = new Marker (place[0].point);
                    gMap.setCenter(mark.getLatLng());
                    gMap.setZoom(8, true);
                    gMap.addOverlay(mark);
                    mark.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK,
                            function setPlaceInfo (e : MapMouseEvent){
                                gMap.openInfoWindow(place[0].point,
                                    new InfoWindowOptions ({title:"Welcome to", content:place[0].address}));
                            });
                });
        placeInfo.addEventListener(GeocodingEvent.GEOCODING_FAILURE, 
                function addFailure(e : GeocodingEvent){
                    trace ('fail to geocode');
                });
        placeInfo.geocode(placeName);
    }
    */
}
```

}

THX before for any help provided....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startMap is directly attached to the stage, and the stage class does not inherit from MovieClip.

You need to change `MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop("mymap");` to `gotoAndStop("mymap");`, or if you're adding startMap to the stage, instead of adding startMap with `stage.addChild(startMapObj);`, you should do `this.addChild(startMapObj);`.

Comment: I've tried this.addChild (myMapObj), but the button didn't appear on stage.... If I use stage.addChild (myMapObj), the button appears still with the error I've mentioned

Comment: If you add it to the stage, then the parent of myMapObj will be the stage, and you cannot send it to a frame (it doesn't even has a frame). You're probably adding something else to the stage and that is covering `this` and also `myMapObj`, if you could explain better how your animations actually work, we could find you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your `moveToMap` method is the `startMap` class itself (which I'm guessing is a MovieClip added to the root stage object). Therefore `this.parent` will resolve to the stage object, and by attempting to cast it to a different type (MovieClip) you're getting the type coercion error.

Is the `mymap` frame label actually on the root timeline? If you want to manipulate the root timeline you have to use Stage's `root` property (and cast it to `MovieClip`). So in your `moveToMap` function it'd look a bit like this:

`MovieClip(stage.root).gotoAndStop("mymap");`

(Note you'll only have access to the `stage` property if your `DisplayObject` is added to the display list).